# How to monitor Window Explorer active directories?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to monitor when the user try to access a certain directory like **J:/** via window explorer. I read about `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` but I really did not understand how to implement into my program. I also read about `GetForegroundWindow` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647399/c-sharp-getforegroundwindow-using-sendmessage). And I also read this [website](http://omegacoder.com/?p=63) which I think it is the closest to what I need but his code did not work like I got nothing when I pressed the button to fetch the active windows, even after adding the "Microsoft Internet Control" reference. 
Using VS 2012
this is how I coded it:

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

string filename;

foreach ( SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows )
{
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ie.FullName ).ToLower();

    if ( filename.Equals( "explorer&quot; ) )
         MessageBox.Show( "Hard Drive : {0}", ie.LocationURL );
}
```

I am writing it wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?
And I apologize in advance if I did any rookie mistakes

Comment: What happens when I use Total Commander or Q-Dir or or the command line?

Comment: This would make sense if you've got a shell extension, but in that case the solution is a lot simpler. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if-condition` to :

```
if (filename.Equals("explorer"))
    MessageBox.Show( "Hard Drive : {0}", ie.LocationURL );
```